# Highlight geometry in Folium map on hover

Tags: python, geometry, style, folium

Is there a way to highlight geometry in Folium on hover along with the `tooltip`?

Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import geopandas


response = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/main/examples/data/us-states.json"
)
data = response.json()
states = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data, crs="EPSG:4326")

response = requests.get(
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tvpmb/4734703/raw/"
    "b54d03154c339ed3047c66fefcece4727dfc931a/US%2520State%2520List"
)
abbrs = pd.read_json(response.text)

income = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pri-data/50-states/master/data/income-counties-states-national.csv",
    dtype={"fips": str},
)
income["income-2015"] = pd.to_numeric(income["income-2015"], errors="coerce")



statesmerge = states.merge(abbrs, how="left", left_on="name", right_on="name")
statesmerge["geometry"] = statesmerge.geometry.simplify(0.05)

statesmerge["medianincome"] = statesmerge.merge(
    income.groupby(by="state")[["state", "income-2015"]].median(),
    how="left",
    left_on="alpha-2",
    right_on="state",
)["income-2015"]
statesmerge["change"] = statesmerge.merge(
    income.groupby(by="state")[["state", "change"]].median(),
    how="left",
    left_on="alpha-2",
    right_on="state",
)["change"]
```

Code:

```
import branca
import folium
from folium.features import GeoJsonPopup, GeoJsonTooltip


colormap = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(
    vmin=statesmerge["change"].quantile(0.0),
    vmax=statesmerge["change"].quantile(1),
    colors=["red", "orange", "lightblue", "green", "darkgreen"],
    caption="State Level Median County Household Income (%)",
)

m = folium.Map(location=[35.3, -97.6], zoom_start=4)


tooltip = GeoJsonTooltip(
    fields=["name", "medianincome", "change"],
    aliases=["State:", "2015 Median Income(USD):", "Median % Change:"],
    localize=True,
    sticky=False,
    labels=True,
    style="""
        background-color: #F0EFEF;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 3px;
    """,
    max_width=800,
)


g = folium.GeoJson(
    statesmerge,
    style_function=lambda x: {
        "fillColor": colormap(x["properties"]["change"])
        if x["properties"]["change"] is not None
        else "transparent",
        "color": "black",
        "fillOpacity": 0.4,
    },
    tooltip=tooltip,
).add_to(m)

colormap.add_to(m)

m
```

On hovering over the folium map it shows the tooltip like below, is there a way to highlight the geometry

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `highlight_function`... For example:

```
folium.GeoJson(
    data=ecmap_gdf["geometry"],
    highlight_function= lambda feat: {'fillColor': 'blue'}
).add_to(m)
```

May be must review the [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-step-up-your-folium-choropleth-map-skills-17cf6de7c6fe).